# How flipping a coin and display tails and heads counting?

Tags: java, random, coin-flipping

I am very beginner on Java, still getting passion about.
I have been given this exercise: "Write a simulator program that flips a coin: One thousand times then prints out how many time you get tails and how many times you get heads"
That is what i have tried to do so far.

```
import java.util.Random; 
import java.util.regex.Pattern; 

public class coin { 

    public static void main( String [] args ) { 

        Random r = new Random(); 
        Pattern tail = Pattern.compile("Tail+"); 
        Pattern head = Pattern.compile("Head+"); 
        String flips = ""; 

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) { 
            flips += r.nextInt(100) % 2 == 0 ? "Head" : "Tail"; 
        } 
        String[] heads = head.split( flips ); 
        String[] tails = tail.split( flips ); 
        //Display
        System.out.println("Times head was flipped:" + heads.length); 
        System.out.println("Times tail was flipped:" + tails.length); 
    }
}
```

The program seems to be working, but it is giving me always an almost pair amount of heads and tails, which the total exceed 1000, at least by 1 or more.
Please, someone has any solution of this? Where am I wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A coin has two sides, so I really don't see why you would ask the random generator to generate a number between 0 and 100 (exclusive). Between 0 and 2 (exclusive) would be much more logical.

Also, you're being asked to count. Appending strings and then splitting to get the final value is quite a complex and inefficient way to count. You should use an integer instead. Each time you get a 1 from your random, increment a counter. In the end, you have the number of times 1 was returned, and the number of 0 is thus 1000 - this number.

```
    Random r = new Random(); 
    int heads = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) { 
        int side = random.nextInt(2);
        if (side == 1) {
            heads++;
        } 
    } 
    System.out.println("Times head was flipped:" + heads); 
    System.out.println("Times tail was flipped:" + (1000 - heads));
```

It could even be simplified to the follwoing (although this simplification makes the code a bit harder to understand):

```
    Random r = new Random(); 
    int heads = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) { 
        heads += random.nextInt(2);
    } 
    System.out.println("Times head was flipped:" + heads); 
    System.out.println("Times tail was flipped:" + (1000 - heads));
```

Answer (score 4):

Rather than appending the result in a String and then splitting the string and counting the occurence of "Head"/"Tail" you can just keep track of the count in separate variables :

```
int headCount = 0;
int tailCount = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    if(r.nextInt(100) %2 == 0)
    {
      headCount++;
    }
    else
    {
      tailCount ++;
    }

  System.out.println("Times head was flipped:" + headsCount); 
  System.out.println("Times tail was flipped:" + tailCount); 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar question for my assessment and I tried below code and it worked. May be its not appropriate way of doing.
I am happy to receive feedback! thanks.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) { 
    flips += r.nextInt(100) % 2 == 1 ? "Head" : "Tail";
}
```

Comment: You'd think that would work, but it doesn't! The question also refers to the fact that the sum of head and tail is not always 1000, but sometimes 999, 998, 1001 or 1002. If you look at the arrays created, you will see the problem. You could rephrase your answer so that the actual problem becomes apparent.